# TS Compiler API - remove semicolons

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

Typescript's printer automatically inserts semicolons, despite having `omitTrailingSemicolon: true`.

**How do I prevent this behavior?**

```
const file = ts.createSourceFile(
  "file",
  'const b = "asd"',
  ts.ScriptTarget.Latest,
  true,
  ts.ScriptKind.TS
);

const printer = ts.createPrinter({
  omitTrailingSemicolon: true,
  removeComments: false,
  newLine: ts.NewLineKind.LineFeed,
});
const printed = printer.printFile(file);
// const b = "asd";\n
```

Comment: Which IDE are you using and which web tool are you using to compile the typescript file?

Comment: @Manjeet It's a part of a vscode extension I'm writing, the IDE is obviously vscode, but I dont think it matters. The snippet above uses TS compiler api to parse a string to an ast and spit it out via the printer, and the printer for whatever reason adds the semicolon

Comment: I think this might be a bug. It works when just printing the variable statement via `printer.printNode(ts.EmitHint.Unspecified, node, sourceFile)`.

Comment: @DavidSherret It seems to work if the node is created via factory functions, but not if the source file (which is also a node) is passed in as node.